# Removing non-printable "gremlin" chars from text files

Tags: python, regex, encoding

I am processing a large number of CSV files in python. The files are received from external organizations and are encoded with a range of encodings. I would like to find an automated method to remove the following:

- Non-ASCII Characters
- Control characters
- Null (ASCII 0) Characters

I have a product called 'Find and Replace It!' that would use regular expressions so a way to solve the above with a regular expression would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: `The files are received from external organizations and are encoded with a range of encodings` - and those are... Ask them not to? What's your related product got to do with this? What are you trying to use the data for... Do you really require Python?

Comment: Good questions. CSV files. Encodings include 'unknown' (according to Find and Replace It!), 'utf-8', 'iso-88591-1' and others. Can't ask them - too many emails, too long. I have already written the python which reformats the CSV files. And the script work in the majority of cases except where gremlins (that somehow do the equivalent of \r) mess up CSV.reader. Removing the non-asciis however encoded would sort me out. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for all of these comments. In the rush to get the work done I have used something called BBEdit which will remove 'gremlins' such as /r characters encoded with an encoding that python does not recognize (without further work). Now that I know how to identify these gremlins using BBEdit, I will check whether any of the solutions below do the same thing and tick the first answer that does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative you might be interested in would be:

```
import string
clean = lambda dirty: ''.join(filter(string.printable.__contains__, dirty))
```

It simply filters out all non-printable characters from the dirty string it receives.

```
>>> len(clean(map(chr, range(0x110000))))
100
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
clean = re.sub('[\0\200-\377]', '', dirty)
```

The idea is to match each NUL or "high ASCII" character (i.e. \0 and those that do not fit in 7 bits) and remove them.  You could add more characters as you find them, such as ASCII ESC or BEL.

Or this:

```
clean = re.sub('[^\040-\176]', '', dirty)
```

The idea being to only permit the limited range of "printable ASCII," but note that this also removes newlines.  If you want to keep newlines or tabs or the like, just add them into the brackets.

Comment: thanks. Will try and come back today. I don't need tabs to be retained but I do need newlines (and hopefully valid CRs within csv enclosures) to be retained, however encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Replace anything that isn't a desirable character with a blank (delete it):

```
clean = re.sub('[^\s!-~]', '', dirty)
```

This allows all whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs etc), and all "normal" characters (`!` is the first ascii printable and `~` is the last ascii printable under decimal 128).

Answer (score 1):

Since this shows up on Google and we're no longer targeting Python 2.x, I should probably mention the `isprintable` method on strings.

It's not perfect, since it sees spaces as printables but newlines and tabs as non-printable, but I'd probably do something like this:

```py
whitespace_normalizer = re.compile('\s+', re.UNICODE)
cleaner = lambda instr: ''.join(x for x in whitespace_normalizer.sub(' ', instr) if x.isprintable())
```

The regex does HTML-like whitespace collapsing (i.e. it converts arbitrary spans of whitespace as defined by Unicode into single spaces) and then the lambda strips any characters other than space that are classified by Unicode as "Separator" or "Other".

Then you get a result like this:

```
>>> cleaner('foo\0bar\rbaz\nquux\tspam eggs')
'foobar baz quux spam eggs'
```